# Laravel eloquent whereHas using value from other relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Let's say destinationCity has a destCityCode value and dispatchDepot has a depotCityCode value.

Order has a hasOne() relationship to a dispatchDepot model and a hasMany() relationship with destinationCity

```
Order::with('destinationCity', 'dispatchDepot')
  ->whereHas('destinationCity', function($q) {
    // is there a way to use values from the dispatchDepot relation in this callback
    // i.e. something like this...?

    $q->where('destCityCode', '=', 'depotCityCode');
  })
  ->get();
```

Is this something where I have to resort to using a join, or is there some way to achieve what I've outlined above using Eloquent?

Many thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Have you tried cretaing a relationship between destinationCity and dispatchDepot based on the  cityCode and other relations they might have? And then accessing it like `Order::with('destinationCity.dispatchDepot')` ?

Comment: Is there related/relation method in DestinationCity that ties DestinationCity and DispatchDepot? Can you post models?

Comment: The actual models and relationships are far more complicated than the example. However, my question was more about how to use a value of one relation in the whereHas of another relation. I actually need to do a whereHas to filter one relation using an adjusted timestamp from another relation.